# Compiling a file that uses an egg

Tags: chicken-scheme

I have the following chicken scheme code:

```
; test.scm
(use coops)
(define-class <Vector2> ()
  (
    (x initform: 0 reader: get-x writer: set-x! )
    (y initform: 0 reader: get-y writer: set-y! )
  )
)

(define v (make <Vector2>))
(print v)
(newline)
```

Running

```
$ csc test.scm
$ ./test
```

gives

```
#<coops instance of `<Vector2>'>
```

which is what I expect.

when I add

```
(declare (uses coops))
```

above

```
(use coop)
```

Running

```
$ csc test.scm
```

Gives

```
test.o: In function `f_494':
test.c:(.text+0x908): undefined reference to `C_coops_toplevel'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Error: shell command terminated with non-zero exit status 256: 'gcc' 'test.o' -o 'test' -L/usr/local/lib  -Wl,-R'/usr/local/lib' -lchicken -lm -ldl
```

What gives? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These declarations are really intended for static linking.

The idea here is that the compiler will generate a call to the toplevel of coops, so that this unit is initialised, but it's not linked into your program (`use` will load and link the extension at runtime into your program).

I know, it's confusing. At least in CHICKEN 5 this stuff has been made a bit simpler. A release candidate for CHICKEN 5 will be made in two weeks if we don't hit any major snags, so it really is quite close to a release!

Comment: Thank you for clearing things up for me.  I went ahead and joined the announce mailing list. I appreciate your time.